# How to create connection string for MVC app in Plesk IIS Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, plesk

I'm new to windows server and have no idea how to create connection string on my IIS windows server for my website. I've already created my MVC website and it's working fine on my localhost. But when I run it on IIS server in Plesk Panel, it gives error "An error occured while processing your request".

Here's my connection string that I'm using.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Seller;user=dev;pwd=Asd123; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What is the instance name of the database you are trying to connect to? Is this a publicly facing website? If not you could set debug="true" in your web.config so you can see the 'actual' error message: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the ip when you posted the connection string ? "Data Source=.;"

it should look like this: "ofcourse you need to change the ip , dbname and credentials that you use for your server"

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=111.111.111.111;Initial Catalog=AwayUsers;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=userpassword"/>
</connectionStrings>
```